# eval() function not working in the calculator project

Tags: javascript

I am trying to finish a calculator project. I have successfully designed the HTML and CSS of the calculator, but facing issues in my JavaScript code. The ERROR coming is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
at HTMLButtonElement.addOutput (logic.js:13)
```

How to sort out the problem? Can anybody help on this?
I have added the complete project code. But the error is mainly in javascript.

The code:
JAVASCRIPT

```
let screen = document.getElementById('screen');
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

function addOutput(e) {
    console.log(e.target.innerText);
    let char = e.target.innerText;
    msg =screen.value += char
    if( char=='C'){
        screen.value=" ";
    }
    else if(char=='=')
    {
        screen.value = eval(msg)
    }
    else{
        msg="";
    }
    
}


for (item of buttons){
    item.addEventListener('click', addOutput);
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="screen_style">
            <h1>Calculator</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="calculator">
                <input type="text" name="screen" id="screen">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><button>(</button></td>
                    <td><button>)</button></td>
                    <td><button>C</button></td>
                    <td><button>%</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button>7</button></td>
                    <td><button>8</button></td>
                    <td><button>9</button></td>
                    <td><button>x</button></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button>4</button></td>
                    <td><button>5</button></td>
                    <td><button>6</button></td>
                    <td><button>-</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button>1</button></td>
                    <td><button>2</button></td>
                    <td><button>3</button></td>
                    <td><button>+</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button>0</button></td>
                    <td><button>.</button></td>
                    <td><button>/</button></td>
                    <td><button>=</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="logic.js"></script>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.screen_style{

    background-color: rgb(135, 222, 208);
    width: 31%;
    border: 1px solid white;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.container{
    text-align: center;
}
table{
    margin: auto;
}
input{
    font-size: 34px;
    border: 4px solid brown;
    border-radius: 21px;
    margin: auto;
}
button{
    font-size: 23px;
    width: 90px;
    height: 75px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    
}
button:hover{
    background-color: rgb(109, 128, 0);
}
.calculator{
    background-color: khaki;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 21px;
    padding: 23px;
}
```

Comment: Please try using the [debugging capabilities](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser. `char` is `=`; `msg` is `screen.value + char`. So what does `msg` contain at the end? Is `msg` a valid expression? `eval` expects valid statements; an expression is a statement.

Comment: Also please [edit] then use the `[<>]` snippet editor to provide a [mcve]

Comment: I am using buttons of calculator and all the buttons have numerical values. I am taking the innerText of the buttons as string. THe eval() function should process the string. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `+=` which is Addition Assignment. So this line,

```
 msg = screen.value += char
```

means

```
msg = screen.value = screen.value + char
```

Which is invalid.
You need to just use a `+` to concatenate the `char` to  `screen.value`.

---

**UPDATE**

You were adding a `=` at the end of `screen.value` which caused `eval` to throw error. You need to check if the `char` is a `=` before concatenating it to `screen.value`.

```js
let screen = document.getElementById('screen');
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

function addOutput(e) {
  let char = e.target.innerText;
  screen.value += ["=", "C"].includes(char) ? "": char
  msg = screen.value
  if (char == 'C') {
    screen.value = " ";
  } else if (char == '=') {
    screen.value = eval(msg)
  } else {
    msg = "";
  }

}



for (item of buttons) {
  item.addEventListener('click', addOutput);
}
```

```css
.screen_style {
  background-color: rgb(135, 222, 208);
  width: 31%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  margin: auto;
}

input {
  font-size: 34px;
  border: 4px solid brown;
  border-radius: 21px;
  margin: auto;
}

button {
  font-size: 23px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 75px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(109, 128, 0);
}

.calculator {
  background-color: khaki;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 21px;
  padding: 23px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="screen_style">
      <h1>Calculator</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="calculator">
      <input type="text" name="screen" id="screen">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><button>(</button></td>
          <td><button>)</button></td>
          <td><button>C</button></td>
          <td><button>%</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button>7</button></td>
          <td><button>8</button></td>
          <td><button>9</button></td>
          <td><button>x</button></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button>4</button></td>
          <td><button>5</button></td>
          <td><button>6</button></td>
          <td><button>-</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button>1</button></td>
          <td><button>2</button></td>
          <td><button>3</button></td>
          <td><button>+</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button>0</button></td>
          <td><button>.</button></td>
          <td><button>/</button></td>
          <td><button>=</button></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="logic.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Techy Sharnav! I have made the necessary changes as given by you. But still I am getting one error: 
VM13961:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='
    at HTMLButtonElement.addOutput (logic.js:13

This happens when I am adding 3+3 and pressing the '=' button

Comment: I have one problem. If I replace += with = My button text is not appearing on the text input field

Comment: @SomduttAcharya Can you add your HTML in your question as well?

Comment: Hi Techy! I have added the HTML and CSS both. You can check now!

Comment: Thanks a ton for helping me out! IT WORKED!. But as I am new to javascript, I am not able to understand this code:
screen.value += ["=", "C"].includes(char) ? "": char
  msg = screen.value
Can you explain?

Comment: @SomduttAcharya So we are conditionally concatenating the value using [`ternary`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). We are using array since it has `includes` method, which checks if an element is present in array or not. If it is present, we add an empty string, else we add the `char`.

Comment: @SomduttAcharya Can you please accept the answer if it helped you?

Comment: @SomduttAcharya Thanks. There is a check button on the left at the top of this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

> msg =screen.value += char

<s>I believe you are trying to add char to screen.value, in which case the += should just be +</s>

---

EDIT: You are adding the char to screen.value before the eval function is called (i.e. eval is getting "5+3=" instead of "5+5".

Updated JavaScript

```
let screen = document.getElementById('screen');
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

function addOutput(e) {
    console.log(e.target.innerText);
    let char = e.target.innerText;
    console.log(screen.value)
    if( char=='C'){
        screen.value=" ";
    }
    else if(char=='=')
    {
        screen.value = eval(screen.value)
    }
    else{
        screen.value += char
    }
    
}


for (item of buttons){
    item.addEventListener('click', addOutput);
}
```

Comment: I have made the necessary changes by replacing += with +. But still I am getting an error.
THE ERROR IS:
VM13961:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='
    at HTMLButtonElement.addOutput (logic.js:13
This error is coming when I am adding two numbers and pressing the = button

Comment: I have one problem. If I replace += with = My button text is not appearing on the text input field –

Comment: I have updated my answer, but if you are using msg for other things outside the addOutput function, I would use the answer @TechySharnav gave

Comment: Thanks again! I think the earlier code was evaluating with '=' inside the string.